# Encoding a string as UTF-8 with BOM in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, byte-order-mark

how can I force PHP to add the BOM when using utf8_encode ?

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
$zip->addFromString($filename, utf8_encode($xml));
```

Unfortunately (for me), the result will not have the BOM mark at the beginning.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Have you tried adding one yourself?

The [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) seems to be `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`, so you can attach it to your string *after* conversion to UTF-8.

```
$utf8_with_bom = chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $utf8_string;
```

Watch out, though.  [`utf8_encode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) wants an ISO-8859-1 string.  If you're working with XML, make sure that the XML isn't *already* UTF-8 encoded.  The comments on the documentation suggest that the function is broken in a variety of fun ways, so you shouldn't throw it around unless you *know* that you need it.

Remember, PHP strings are simply dumb, unknowing bytes.  They don't have a character set attached to them, so if the data in the string is already UTF-8, you don't need to run the conversion.

Also, the linked Wikipedia article says this:

> While Unicode standard allows BOM in UTF-8, **it does not require or recommend it.  Byte order has no meaning in UTF-8** so a BOM only serves to identify a text stream or file as UTF-8 or that it was converted from another format that has a BOM.

You probably don't need to bother with the BOM tapdance to begin with.

Comment: I had a problem where Excel wouldn't open my UTF-8 CSV correctly without the BOM so it may not be required but it certainly can make a difference.

Comment: You can make the number seem less "magical" by doing `chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF)` - this way you can see that it's hex, and from there understand better that it's the BOM.

Comment: If you use some old editor, e.g. EditPlus, then 'find in file' function can only search and recognize file with foreign characters encoded in utf8+bom.

Comment: Keep in mind that for the .CSV file to work in Excel for Mac, UTF8 BOM and encoding won't work - you need to convert your data to UTF16-LE *and* add a UTF16-LE BOM - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16766198/324220

Comment: I pledge to you my firstborn child. Thank you.