# PHP fwrite function to write txt file in utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, arabic, fwrite

I have made a form where a user writes his message in Arabic and submits it by a submit button. The message is saved in database and I need to create a .txt file on the server for some other application which shows something like this :

> Ø¯ Ù¾ÙˆÙ„ÙŠØ³Ùˆ Ù¾Ø

I successfully used the fopen, fwrite functions to create my txt files.

When I open the file in notepad the Arabic text is shown correctly
but when I open it in eclipse I get something like this :

> Ø¯ Ù¾ÙˆÙ„ÙŠØ³Ùˆ Ù¾Ø± Ø±ÙˆØ²Ù†ÙŠØ² Ù…Ø±Ú©Ø² ØªÙˆØºÙ†Ø¯ÙˆÙŠÙŠ Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ ÙˆØ´Ùˆ

Well afterwards when I save the txt file in notepad as utf-8 encoding the above unknown stuff changes to Arabic.
But I cant do that manually for every message.

I searched a lot on the internet and did these:

1. I saved the script in utf-8
2. I used `utf8_encode` function
3. I set this too `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`
4. this too `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8; encoding=utf-8" />`
5. I change the parameter in fwrite to "wb" where b is for binary

Any solution to this problem ill be very glad I have continuously worked on this issue for the last week. I know the problem is in the encoding so how can I write utf-8 encoded files using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text displays fine in one program but not another, that just means one program interprets the file correctly while the other doesn't. Most likely Notepad sets a [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) on the file when you save it again, so Eclipse now automatically recognizes that it's UTF-8 encoded. Without that, Eclipse assumes latin-1 or some other encoding as the default.

Two options:

- change your Eclipse preferences to open files as UTF-8 by default
- set a BOM on the file when writing it, see [Encoding a string as UTF-8 with BOM in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601904/encoding-a-string-as-utf-8-with-bom-in-php)

A BOM can be helpful for making programs recognize UTF-8 but can also cause problems in other programs that don't expect or want BOMs. Whether to use a BOM or not depends on your intended use and target audience.

Comment: i followed the link and did this to my string: $utf8_with_bom = chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $string; thanks man u guys are lifesavers

Comment: Good. Just be aware that a BOM is not required for UTF-8 and some programs don't understand it. In those the BOM will show up as three funny squiggles at the very start of the file. You can find much information about this if you googler a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you need to set your encoding in menu **Edit** > **Set Encoding...**