# Exporting CSV to excel in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mime-types

I made a CSV as an example:

```
Type, जिल्ला शिक्षा कार्यालय डडेलधुरा,NGOI,NGO Request,21,0,0 Response, 4,0,0
```

and it has utf-8 characters and i want to export it to excel so i posted it and to export it to excel and after referring to several questions on stackoverflow i did as follow:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
print $_POST['csv_data'];exit;
```

the csv is exported to excel nicely but character encoding in not converted and shows something like this: `à¤œà¤¿à¤²à¥à¤²à¤¾ à¤¶à¤¿à¤•à¥à¤·à¤¾ à¤•à¤¾à¤°à¥à¤¯à¤¾à¤²à¤¯ à¤¡à¤¡à¥‡à¤²à¤§à¥à¤°à¤¾` and when i add

```
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

the character encoding is converted but the data appears in one column like this:

```
Type, जिल्ला शिक्षा कार्यालय डडेलधुरा,NGOI,NGO
Request,21,0,0
Response, 4,0,0
```

Comment: Use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)! Self-made solutions are definitly not useful.

Comment: You can try to add `utf8_encode()` to the `$_POST['csv_data']`

Comment: @JackPoint the result comes like this `Ã Â¤ÂœÃ Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â²Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â²Ã Â¤Â¾ Ã Â¤Â¶Ã Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â•Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â·Ã Â¤Â¾ Ã Â¤Â•Ã Â¤Â¾Ã Â¤Â°Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â¯Ã Â¤Â¾Ã Â¤Â²Ã Â¤Â¯ Ã Â¤Â¡Ã Â¤Â¡Ã Â¥Â‡Ã Â¤Â²Ã Â¤Â§Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â°Ã Â¤Â¾`

Answer (score 1):

UTF8 + CSV + Excel is known to be a problematic combination. Excel just isn't very good at importing CSV.

One thing you should try is to add a [UTF8 BOM character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601904/encoding-a-string-as-utf-8-with-bom-in-php) at the start of your CSV file; that might help Excel work out what to do with it.

I'm optimistic that will help, but if it doesn't, you may have to re-think using CSV for this.

Other options you could use instead of CSV would include XML, and creating an actual Excel file from within PHP (there are a number of libraries available which can do this, the best one being [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)).

Hope that helps.