# Encoding issue with PHP while writing in a .csv file

Tags: php, web-scraping, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm working with a php array which contains some values parsed from a previous scraping process (using `Simple HTML DOM Parser`). I can normally `print` / `echo`  the values of this array, which contains special chars `é,à,è`, etc. **BUT**, the problem is the following :

When I'm using `fwrite` to save values in a .csv file, some characters are not successfully saved. For example, `Székesfehérvár` is well displayed on my php view in `HTML`, but saved as `Sz&#233;kesfeh&#233;rv&#225;r` in the `.csv` file which I generate with the php script above.

I've already set-up several things in the php script :

- The page I'm **scraping** seems to be utf-8 encoded
- My PHP script is also declared as utf-8 in the header
- I've tried a lot of `iconv` and `mb_encode` methods in different places in the code
- **NOTE** that when I'm make a JS console.log of my php array, using json_encode, the characters are also broken, maybe linked to the original encoding of the page I'm scraping?

Here's a part of the script, it is the part who is writing values in a `.csv` file

```php
<?php 

$data = array(
            array("item1", "item2"), 
            array("item1", "item2"),
            array("item1", "item2"),
            array("item1", "item2")
            // ...
);

//filename
$filename = 'myFileName.csv';

foreach($data as $line) {
    $string_txt = ""; //declares the content of the .csv as a string
    foreach($line as $item) {
        //writes a new line of the .csv
        $line_txt = "";
        //each line of the .csv equals to the values of the php subarray, tab separated
        $line_txt .= $item . "\t";
    }

    //PHP endline constant, indicates the next line of the .csv
    $line_txt .= PHP_EOL;
    
    //add the line to the string which is the global content of the .csv
    $line_txt .= $string_txt;
}

//writing the string in a .csv file 
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($file, $string_txt);
fclose($file);
```

I am currently stuck because I can't save values with accentuated characters correctly.

Comment: _“The page i'm scrapping seems to be utf-8 encoded”_ - it much rather seems, that the page you are scraping actually uses these numeric entities to represent these characters already. You probably just haven’t noticed, because you looked at your debug outputs _after_ the browser has interpreted them as HTML. `html_entity_decode` should help.

Comment: @misorude, thanks for your help. I don't really understand your comment, let me add that : when I do a `print_r` of my `$data` array, all the characters are availables, but the problem is when I try to do something else with this array, such as a `json_encode` for JS, or write in  a .csv. Do you understand what I mean ? thx

Comment: Do a `print_r("Sz&#233;kes");` - notice something?

Comment: Yes, the `print_r` return `Székes`. Following you, I use `htmlentities` to get the _original_ numeric entities of the values, but my question is now : How can I **store** the values as `Székes` for example, and not as `Sz&#233;kes` ? thx @misorude

Comment: _“Yes, the `print_r` return `Székes`”_ - so do you understand my initial comment now then? _“How can I store the values as `Székes` for example, and not as `Sz&#233;kes` ?”_ - by making the value that you have, into the value that you want – you currently _have_ `Sz&#233;kes`. And no, I did not say to use `htmlentities`.

Comment: Sorry but while using `html_entity_decode`, I still can't write the right value in a file. exemple : 
`fwrite($file, html_entity_decode("S&#243"));` is writing `S&#243`, while `echo html_entity_decode("S&#243");` is echoing `Só`. Did I miss something in your explications ? sorry ...

Comment: `&#243;` would be a numeric HTML character reference - `&#243` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution** (provided by @misorude) :

When **scraping** HTML contents from webpages, there is a difference between what's *displayed* in your debug and what's really **scraped** in the script. I had to use `html_entity_decode` to let PHP interpret the *true* value of the HTML code I've **scraped**, and not the browser's interpretation.

To validate a good retriving of values before store them somewhere, you could try a console.log in JS to see if values are correctly drived :

**PHP**

```
//decoding numeric HTML entities who represents "Sóstói Stadion"
$b = html_entity_decode("S&#243;st&#243;i Stadion");
```

**Javascript** (to test):

```
<script>
var b = <?php echo json_encode($b) ;?>;

//print "Sóstói Stadion" correctly
console.log(b); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, but it's already in the script, but I simplified the code part for the post. (also mentioned in the text: "My PHP script is also declared as utf-8 in the header"). thx

Comment: Can you please check once by select encoding type: UTF-8 when you are going to open downloaded CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$file = fopen('myFileName.csv','w');
$data= array_map("utf8_decode", $data);
fputcsv($file,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel has problems displaying utf8 encoded csv files. I saw this before. But you can try utf8 BOM. I tried it and works for me. This is simply adding these bytes at the start of your utf8 string:

```
$line_txt .= chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $item . "\t";
```

For more info:
[Encoding a string as UTF-8 with BOM in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601904/encoding-a-string-as-utf-8-with-bom-in-php)

Alternatively, you can use the file import feature in Excel and make sure the file origin says `65001 : Unicode(UTF8)`. It should display your text properly and you will need to save it as an Excel file to preserve the format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally found the answer by using `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, with a function for removing the BOM:

```
function removeBomUtf8($s)
{
    if (substr($s,0,3) == chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF'))) {
        return substr($s,3);
    } else {
        return $s;
    }
}

$data = array_map(function ($d) { return true ? strtoupper(removeBomUtf8($d)) : strtoupper(iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $d)); }, $data);
```