# Create csv file using django and directly open into Excel

Tags: django, excel, csv, unicode

I have created the csv file through django. I have write the encoded data into that. but when i open this file in excel sheet then the unicode characters not display properly.

I also refer this question
[Django create CSV file that contains Unicode and can be opened directly with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846133/django-create-csv-file-that-contains-unicode-and-can-be-opened-directly-with-exc)

But didn't get the proper answer. I have tried all the answers, but didn't work any of them.

I write the code as below.

```
    def exportcsv(request):
        import csv
        producer_list = Producer.objects.filter()
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=producer.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
        writer.writerow(['Produsenter','Type','Land','Region'])
        for cdst in producer_list:
            writer.writerow([cdst.title.encode("UTF-8"),
                            cdst.producer_type.encode("UTF-8"),
                            cdst.country.country.encode("UTF-8"),
                            cdst.region.region.encode("UTF-8")])
        return response
```

Then the csv file created properly, but the characters in that not encoded properly.
The character will be display like "Tokaj HÃ©tszÃ¶lÃ¶".

When i try

```
writer.writerow([cdst.title.encode("iso-8859-1"),
                            cdst.producer_type.encode("iso-8859-1"),
                            cdst.country.country.encode("iso-8859-1"),
                            cdst.region.region.encode("iso-8859-1")])
```

Then the data will we added properly also open it excel file properly.
But it give error for some characters like 'æ' and ' in the string.

Error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 266: ordinal not in range(256)

I also try the below code.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=producer.csv'
response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=",")
```

Also try

```
writer.writerow(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
writer.writerow(str.decode('utf8').encode('utf_16_le'))
```

Comment: Wwhile this is not a real answer, you should try tablib which allows exporting xls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve above issue. I write the code as below.

```
writer.writerow([cdst.title.encode("iso-8859-1"),
                 cdst.producer_type.encode("iso-8859-1"),
                 cdst.country.country.encode("iso-8859-1"),
                 cdst.region.region.encode("iso-8859-1")])
```

using above code i got the error as

```
Error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 266: ordinal not in range(256)
```

But this error is because of empty string and for '-' character when i pass to encoding. This can be resolved when i set condition before passing the string to encoding and replace the '-' character with '_'.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv). It solved similiar troubles for me.