# How to fix error font UTF8 in file csv when export file csv in php

Tags: php

I export csv in php as:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

            foreach ($list as $fields) {
                if(!empty($fields))
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
                else
                fputcsv($fp, ' ');

            }
            $fp = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($fp,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8"); 
            fclose($fp);
```

When i open csv, font UTF_8 is error.
Ex: 防本部コー show in file csv: æ¶ˆé˜²æœ¬éƒ¨ă‚³ăƒ¼ăƒ‰

Can I help you? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed here:

[How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly)

You might also want to check your CSV in an alternative text editor to rule out the editor.

Answer (score 1):

`$fp` is a pointer resource to a file. It is not a string, you cannot do this:

```
$fp = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($fp,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
```

To write UTF-16 data to the file, you need to convert it before writing it, not after the fact:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

fwrite($fp, chr(255).chr(254));

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    foreach ($fields as &$field) {
        $field = mb_convert_encoding($field, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Don't know if this actually outputs the data you need, but it fixes the obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function will work:

```
public static function exportCSVFile($data = array(), $headers = array(), $delimiter = ",", $csvfilename = "CSVFile") {
        ob_clean();
        ob_start();
        $csvfilename = $csvfilename . "_" . date("Y_m_d_h_i_s") . ".csv";
        $file_handler = fopen("php://output", 'w');
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/csv");
        //header( "Content-Type: application/csv;charset=utf-8" );
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$csvfilename}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        foreach ($data as $fields) {
            $_str = implode($delimiter, $fields);
            $fields = explode($delimiter, utf8_decode($_str));
            fputcsv($file_handler, $fields, $delimiter, $enclosure = '"');
        }
        fclose($file_handler);
        ob_flush();
        exit();
    }
```