# Is content-encoding being set to UTF-8 invalid?

Tags: java, apache, http

Hi I have a client that is trying to POST to us with the following http headers:

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-encoding: UTF-8
```

But our web application firewall keeps picking them up and throwing error:

> Message:  [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/10_asl_rules.conf"] [line "45"] [id "340362"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: ModSecurity does not support content encodings and can not detect attacks using it, therefore it must be blocked."] [severity "WARNING"] Access denied with code 501 (phase 2). Match of "rx ^Identity$" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Encoding" required.
>   Action: Intercepted (phase 2)

Anyone would like to shed some light into this matter?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is invalid. The `content-encoding` specifies the *data transfer encoding* used by the issuer of the content. UTF-8 is not a content encoding, it is a character set. Specifying the character set is done in the `content-type` header:

```
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Valid content-encoding values are, for instance, `gzip`, `deflate`. An HTTP *client* should specify what content encoding it supports with the `accept-encoding` header; the HTTP *server* will reply with a `content-encoding` header.

Comment: could you provide a reference to where you obtained your content-encoding values? i've only found these to be valid: identity, gzip, and deflate.

Comment: also, should content-encoding, not be passed at all? what would happen in that case?

Comment: @fge those are valid `Content-Transfer-Encoding` values for MIME email, which is not *quite* the same thing.

Comment: @JaeLee if you don't pass a Content-Encoding, the data is not compressed at all

Comment: @JaeLee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding