# Can't encode CSV file in UTF8 with PHP

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

I've been trying, for some time now, to export a properly encoded and formated CSV file with PHP. But it's just not working. I've tried every tip in every CSV/PHP related thread on SOF, I've checked that the data in my database is UTF-8, it is. I've tried stuff like utf8_encode() on the whole CSV-line, I've checked that the actual PHP file is encoded in UTF-8, but still no success. When I run the file on http://csvlint.io/ I just get:

> Your CSV appears to be encoded in ASCII-8BIT. We recommend you use UTF-8.

But I can't find a trace of any other encoding than UTF-8 anywhere in my code..
Basically this is my code:

First, I put all my CSV-rows in an array, then do this:

```
if (count($array) == 0)
{
    return NULL;
}
ob_start();
$df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
$csv = utf8_encode("header1|header2|header3|header4|header5|header6|header7\r\n");
foreach($array as $line) {
    $csv .= $line . "\r\n";
}
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE', "swedish");
fwrite($df, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$csv);
fclose($df);
return ob_get_clean();
```

And these are the headers sent:

```
$now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) you're prepending to the output in this line:

```
fwrite($df, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$csv);
```

If you change this to simply

```
fwrite($df, $csv);
```

You should find the resulting file validates just fine (or at least, the validator doesn't complain about its encoding).

Arguably this is a problem with the *validator*, since as the Wikipedia article notes,

> The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8, but does not require or recommend its use.

I don't recommend you use it either, as most software seems not to recognize byte-order marks. But if you *must* or you simply prefer to, you can safely ignore the warning from CSVLint.

---

Since that is apparently not the issue, the next thing I'd look at is whether or not the data is being *retrieved* from the database in UTF-8. (I'll take your word you've already checked carefully to make sure the data is being *stored* in UTF-8.) If you're using MySQL, this will depend on the configuration of the database server and any options you may be sending the database after connection.

The PHP manual has [a section on character sets and MySQL](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php), and there is also [this helpful article](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql) about using PHP and MySQL together with UTF-8 data. If you're using a different database system, it likely has equivalent configuration options that should be checked.

The only other suggestions I can make are that you

- Move the call to `setlocale` higher in the script, before string concatenation begins in the `foreach` loop. (I don't *think* this setting affects simple concatenation, but I'm not certain.)
- Remove the `Content-Encoding` header from your output, as [it is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154967/is-content-encoding-being-set-to-utf-8-invalid) the way it is currently being used.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the answer, but I tried this earlier (and now again just to be sure), and it's not working. One could of course choose not to trust the validator, but I think it's correct because I have some Swedish characters in the data that are not displayed correctly, ie:
"Uppr��ttande av" should be "Upprättande av"

Comment: @nyy, I've updated my answer with further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
$filename = 'csv/'.date('Y-m-d_H:i:s').'.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

foreach ($csvData as $fields) {
    fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, $delimiter = ';');
}

fclose($fp);
```