# Why the response doesn't contain `Content-Encoding` header?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Why the response doesn't contain `Content-Encoding` header?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace MyServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var listener = new HttpListener();
           listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8001/");
           listener.Start();
           var context = listener.GetContext();
           var response = context.Response;
           response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
           response.ContentType = "application/json";
           var json = "{'message':'Привет, мир!'}";
           var jsonBytes = response.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(json);
           response.ContentLength64 = jsonBytes.LongLength;
           response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
           response.OutputStream.Write(jsonBytes,0,jsonBytes.Length);
           response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is content-encoding being set to UTF-8 invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154967/is-content-encoding-being-set-to-utf-8-invalid)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, no. `HttpListenerResponse.ContentEncoding` property has `Encoding type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is not a valid content encoding in this case.

See also: [Is content-encoding being set to UTF-8 invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154967/is-content-encoding-being-set-to-utf-8-invalid)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Encoding: compress
Content-Encoding: deflate
Content-Encoding: identity
Content-Encoding: br

// Multiple, in the order in which they were applied
Content-Encoding: gzip, identity
Content-Encoding: deflate, gzip
```

Comment: Hm... But `HttpListenerResponse.ContentEncoding` property has `Encoding` type. It can't to be *gzip*, *compress*, etc. It seems that in .NET this property should point to the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could specify encoding like this

```
response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

See more at [What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean)

But like it is said there : charset for json response is redundant