# Express body-parser v.1.19.0 Content-Encoding issue

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Using body-parser v.1.19.0 in my service. There is a service that calls into my express server that has `Content-Encoding: UTF-8` in the incoming header. Their service deals with other apps also, so not sure a quick solution would be fixed on their end. But in my server this causes error `unsupported content encoding "utf-8"`.

Is there any solution in dealing with this incoming header from a body-parser standpoint? I have seen some solutions but they seem like bandaids.

One solution is to catch it in a middleware before it gets to body-parser and `delete` it. But it seems this might be a performance concern using `delete`

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    delete req.headers['content-encoding'];
    next();
});
```

Or just redefine it to empty string also works so as to not use the `delete` command

```
req.headers['content-encoding'] = '';
```

These seem like bandaids instead of addressing the incoming header and dealing with it. Is there some accepted solution when dealing with `Content-Encoding` in an express service with body-parser?

Comment: What version of Node.js do you use?

Comment: @Anatoly currently running 12.13.1

Comment: Then you should use Express.js parser instead of body-parser

Comment: I will take a look at it. Thanks @Anatoly

Comment: Seems I get the same error there - UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported content encoding "utf-8"

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17155003/1376618