# How can i add encoding to the python generated CSV file

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I am following this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016545

and i want to know that how can i do that in Python. I don't know how can i insert BOM data in there

This is my current code

```
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="results.csv"'
    writer = UnicodeWriter(response, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="utf-8")
```

I want to convert to utf -16 . BOm data is this but don't know how to insert it
From here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440143

`echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM`

But i want it for python and utf-16

I tried opening that csv in notepad and insert `\xef\xbb\xb` in beginning and excel displayed that correctly. But it is also visible before first column.

How can i hide that because user wont like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these lines write the correct BOM for the encoding.  If the BOM is correct, Excel should not display it.

```
writer = UnicodeWriter(response, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

or:

```
writer = UnicodeWriter(response, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="utf16")
```

`utf8`, `utf-16le` and `utf-16be` *do not* write a BOM.

Comment: ok so u mean i dont need to write `echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";` any where in the BOM

Comment: where can i find more info about BOM . i could not find any where

Comment: I have seen that it works on PC and Excel but its not working on MAx Excel 2011. i am using `8-sig`. Do u know which thing can  work in Excel for mac

Comment: Try without the BOM on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting the wrong BOM. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16 it suggests you should use FF FE or FE FF (depending upon big or little endian)

The python docs (at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) suggest there is an encoding setting for utf-16. In addition 'there are variants of these encodings, such as ‘utf-16-le’ and ‘utf-16-be’ for little-endian and big-endian encodings'. Perhaps these will allow the BOM to be inserted automatically during writing.

Comment: i want to know , how to insert BOM in python