# Header Content Type Charset UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: php, character-encoding, header, content-type, encode

Im currently making a file that some have to download and upload. The file have som differents encodings and it only works if the file is opened with UTF-8 with BOM.

Currently im using this simple header `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` but how can i change the settings so file file would be seen as UTF-8 with BOM.

Hoping for some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to include a BOM in an HTML file. (If it really includes different encodings, then a UTF-8 BOM would be broken, so it sounds like you're a bit confused.)

If you expect the file to be saved to disk and used in places where UTF-8 isn't expected, you could add a meta element to indicate the encoding as well:

`<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`

If in fact you are using a different encoding than UTF-8, then rather than a BOM, just change the value in the meta attribute.

If you really must have a BOM in there then you'll need to make sure that it's first thing you output, e.g.

`echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";`

See [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly%20How%20can%20I%20output%20a%20UTF-8%20CSV%20in%20PHP%20that%20Excel%20will%20read%20properly?) for an example where that actually makes sense.

Comment: Thanks mate! Good to know that it isnt needed. I will try just using UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, the hex gave the correct magic spell. Microsoft should fix their apps.