# Wordpress export not working for arabic string

Tags: php, wordpress, xls

I am trying to export my post data into csv/xls but both return '???' instead of arabic string. I have set headers...

```php
//output the headers for the XLS file
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-Type: Application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add this to the end of the header output?

```
print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($csv_output, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

[Found it here](https://gist.github.com/basmahBM/be05c3879cda8ffa3b9a972cf700ec52) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592707/php-export-csv-when-data-having-utf8-charcters) .