# How to remove a blank row from the CSV file created using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv, blank-line

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create a CSV file using the below code. The problem I am facing is that I am getting a blank row at the top of the CSV file. Please see my code here:

```
    $fileName = 'Feedback.csv';

    $AllFeedData = $this->GetData($datefrom,$dateto,$screen);

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
        "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires"             => "0"
    );

    $columns = array('MRN No', 'Patient Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Doctor', 'Total Rating', 'Feedback Status', 'Question', 'Rating', 'Mobile', 'Email', 'Invoice No', 'Invoice Date');

    try
    {
        $callback = function() use($AllFeedData, $columns) {
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
            fputcsv($file, $columns);
            foreach ($AllFeedData as $AllData) {

                $row['MRN No']    = $AllData->pfc_ptno;
                $row['Patient Name']    = $AllData->pfc_ptname;

                if($AllData->pfc_gender == 'F'){
                    $row['Gender'] = 'Female';
                }elseif ($AllData->pfc_gender == 'M'){
                    $row['Gender'] = 'Male'; 
                }else{
                    $row['Gender'] = 'Other'; 
                }
                
                $row['Age']  = $AllData->pfn_yearage;
                $row['Doctor'] = $AllData->pfc_docname;
                $row['Total Rating'] = $AllData->pfn_totrating;

                if($AllData->pfc_status == "F"){
                    $row['Feedback Status'] = 'Completed';
                }elseif ($AllData->pfc_status == "P"){
                    $row['Feedback Status'] = 'Partially Completed'; 
                }elseif ($AllData->pfc_status == "N"){
                    $row['Feedback Status'] = 'Pending'; 
                }

                $row['Question']  = $AllData->qfc_question;
                $row['Rating']  = $AllData->pfn_rating;
                $row['Mobile']    = $AllData->pfc_mobile;
                $row['Email']    = strtolower($AllData->pfc_email);
                $row['Invoice No']  = $AllData->pfc_invno;
                $row['Invoice Date']  = $AllData->pfd_invdate;
                
                fputcsv($file, array($row['MRN No'], $row['Patient Name'], $row['Gender'], $row['Age'], $row['Doctor'], $row['Total Rating'], $row['Feedback Status'], $row['Question'], $row['Rating'], $row['Mobile'], $row['Email'], $row['Invoice No'], $row['Invoice Date']));
            }
            fclose($file);
        };
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        report($e);
 
        return false;
    }

    return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}
```

Screenshot of the exported CSV file is attached below. Please note the highlighted row which I need to be removed.

[image: Screenshot of the CSV file]

Comment: look if this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169080/blank-line-at-the-beginning-when-writing-a-csv-file-in-php helps you

Comment: Thank you @GiacomoM, the issue is solved after using ob_clean();

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).