# Fail adding BOM to my exported csv file

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, export-to-csv, byte-order-mark

I want to export a mysql database, which contains Chinese Characters, to a csv file. 
The original encoding of the mysql data is UTF-8, but when I export it to csv, the excel cannot display the chinese character. 
I know the problem is that I need to add BOM the encoding, I have follow the steps people taught but it doesn't work. May I ask anyone can help. please??
This the code I have:`

```
header("Content-type:text/csv; charset=utf-8-sig"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$v_scrn.".csv"); 
header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0'); 
header('Expires:0'); 
header('Pragma:public'); 
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
echo $data;
```

Comment: The first echo produces the correct UTF-8 BOM. I have never seen `charset=utf-8-sig`, always just `charset=utf-8`. In which way is your code broken? What does not work for you?

Comment: You may also want to [convert your data from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4762708/570812).

Comment: I have tried UTF-8, UTF-16LE, but none works...I have no idea which part went wrong, just I can't see the Chinese characters displayed.

Comment: To clarify, the csv is successfully exported, when I open in Notepad++, it tells me that it is encoded with UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM, even though I have already add [echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";] this line...Please may someone tell me why???? THANKS!

Comment: OHH I found out what's wrong!
I have to put the [echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";] at the very beginning of the code,
just after <?php
don't know why, but it works! thanks all your reply anyway :)