# Convert unicode Ã Â°Â¨Ã Â±Â‡Ã Â°Â¨Ã Â±Â Ã into normal unicode message

Tags: php, unicode

I am getting this output when run one page  :

Ã Â°Â¨Ã Â±Â‡Ã Â°Â¨Ã Â±Â Ã

I need to convert this message into unicode message

thanks

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information than you posted. http://www.biostars.org/p/75548/

Comment: @biostars.org 
Dear Sir,
I am trying to implement One CSV file for Download from database rows 
But instead of local language i am getting 
Ã Â°Â¨Ã Â±Â‡Ã Â°Â¨Ã Â±Â Ã like this code.....:)

Comment: CSV is being saved in UTF-8 encoding, but Excel is reading it in as code page 1252 Western European. You can persuade Excel to import as UTF-8 instead by putting a fake-BOM (bytes `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"`) at the start of the CSV file (though this is a bit dodgy and it's not the only problem with Excel's CSV import). However also the data were lightly mangled before they were output in UTF-8—it looks like they've been transcoded from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 even though they were already UTF-8. Possibly `utf8_encode()` is being inappropriately called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very much like you are outputting unicode (more precise: utf-8 encoded characters) correctly, but don't declare it in your Content-Type, so the browser assumes it's iso-8859-1 and displays it like that.

Something like

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

should help.

Comment: @GuntramBlom Thanks a lot..for Ur reply ...it was working fine when i am calling from browser. But when i am trying to download the data as a csv file format but i am getting à°…à°¸à±à°¦à±à°˜à°¸

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly/4762708#4762708