# VBA importing UTF-8 CSV file from a web server

Tags: excel, vba, csv, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 CSV file stored on a web server. When I download the file put it on my hard drive and I then import it into an Excel sheet with this macro (from the macro recorder) :

```
Sub Macro2()
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    "C:/myFile.csv", Origin _
    :=65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
End Sub
```

All of the characters (vietnamese characters) are displayed correctly.

When I try the same macro but instead of giving the local address of the file ("C:/myFile.csv") I pass the URL of the file ("http://myserver.com/myFile.csv") the CSV is correctly imported into my Excel sheet but the vietnamese characters are not displayed correctly anymore.

I have also tried using the Data tab but the encoding seems be ignored by Excel:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "TEXT;C:/myFile.csv" _
                , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                .Name = "myFile.csv"
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                .TextFilePlatform = 65001
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "~"
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
       End With
```

Sample data: `Â„; Â; Â˜; Â1/4; Â‰; Â™,Â™`

which Excel reads wrongly as: `Ã‚â€ž; Ã‚; Ã‚Ëœ; Ã‚1/4; Ã‚â€°; Ã‚â„¢,Ã‚â„¢;`

Comment: There is usually an encoding declaration in HTTP headers. Maybe in your case it is set to another character set and overwrite the `Origin` parameter

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how i can change those HTTP headers ?

Comment: Depends on the server. You can easily check if that is the case with a web browser: in firefox you can activate the web console, type the URL in the address bar and look at the response header `Content-type`

Comment: here is the content-type : text/html; charset=UTF-8 So it shouldn't be a server issue no ? thanks

Comment: No it shouldn't. Maybe Excel ignores it..

Comment: My testing shows that Excel gets confused when there is no Unicode byte order mark in the file. When there is one, it opens it properly from a URL, and in that case it does not matter whether the server supplies  charset=UTF-8 in the headers.

Comment: @GSerg ... I've just verified that all the files I am opening are `UTF-8`, opening those manually while recording a macro sets the `Origin:=65001`. As soon as I removed the Origin completely the files open just fine... I think this may have been an Excel's bug (either macro recorder or simply `UTF-8` has nothing to do with the Excel's `65001`... don't know but I am glad it's working after removing the Origin parameter

Answer (score 8):

I have been looking at a similar problem where we import utf-8 encoded csv files in to a worksheet. I am not pulling the data from a web server but this might help.

My solution is to read the utf-8 file to a local variable then insert it into a sheet. I tried saving the data to a temp file with ansi encoding but doing this caused all the characters to lose their accents.

```
Function ReadUTF8CSVToSheet(file As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strText As String

    ' read utf-8 file to strText variable
   With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1  ' Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
        .LoadFromFile file
        .Type = 2  ' Private Const adTypeText = 2
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        strText = .ReadText(-1)  ' Private Const adReadAll = -1
    End With

    ' parse strText data to a sheet
    Set ws = Sheets.Add()
    intRow = 1
    For Each strLine In Split(strText, chr(10))
        If strLine <> "" Then
            With ws
                .Cells(intRow, 1) = strLine
                .Cells(intRow, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(intRow, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
            End With

            intRow = intRow + 1
        End If
    Next strLine

    ReadUTF8CSVToSheet = ws.Name

End Function

' to run
strSheetName = ReadUTF8CSVToSheet("C:\temp\utf8file.csv")
```

Answer (score 7):

If the characters are displayed correctly when you download the `csv` file yourself, I'd divide the process to 2 stages:

### Downloading

```
Sub DownloadFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal local As String)

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile local, 2 
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

### Loading CSV

```
Sub OpenCsv(ByVal csvfile As String)
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _ 
csvfile,Local:=True,StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
End Sub
```

**Note That:** The `Local` parameter is the key here,it makes `VBA` use your excel's  local configuration (vietnamese), which is by default set to `False`.

### Putting it all together

```
Sub DownloadAndLoad
  DownloadFile "http://myserver.com/myFile.csv","C:\myFile.csv"
  OpenCsv "C:\myFile.csv"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Uri. Thanks for your reply. In my case, the `Local:=True` doesn't change a thing (is it cause my locals are UK? Changing my locale isn't really an option as I will be processing files of many languages...). For example, the csv file has a `Â™` in it, when I use the `Workbooks.Open` the character is still loaded as `Ã‚Â„¢`. I have noticed that when I do this manually (not via macro) the csv is loaded properly. I have recorded a macro from the manual steps but the macro behaviour is different. I have read that csv files may be missing UTF-8 heading - are you familiar with headings at all?

Comment: `Local` should not be used or have an effect when reading UTF-8. @Meehow Yes, putting a [UTF-8 BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4348802/11683) in the file [fixes it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626622/vba-importing-utf-8-csv-file-from-a-web-server#comment52533489_23626622).

Answer (score 4):

IMO, there seems to be a bug/conflict in Excel when opening UTF-8/UTF-8-BOM files using the recorded macro code, specifically when the `Origin` parameter is set to `65001` which is *supposed* be UTF-8.

I have found two workarounds to this issue:

1. Remove the `Origin` parameter from the function call and see if the file loads properly `Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\file.csv"`.

   [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx):

   > If this argument is omitted, the method uses the current setting of
   >   the File Origin option in the Text Import Wizard.

   I would think that as soon as you link the file with Excel, it should try to read the header of the file and select the correct [Country Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) automatically (*well, assuming the header is not missing*).
2. I have tried different [Country Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) and found that in my specific scenario setting `Origin:=1252` (*`1252 - windows-1252 - ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows)`*) loads the file in Excel just fine.