# How remove BOM mark from download file?

Tags: php, phpexcel, byte-order-mark

I have this script to let the user download file:

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qa_report.xlsx");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
// echo excel file ...
exit;
```

The file always have a BOM marker, how can't I remove the BOM marker?

Comment: How are you creating the "Excel" output? Is it perhaps just CSV with a fake mime type?

Comment: @mario Yes i am creating "Excel" output. no its no fake, when i open the file with HEX editor and remove the BOM the file is working else i cant read the file with excel.

Comment: Then check all your PHP scripts for BOM markers.

Comment: See if this Q&A helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/4348802/ - You can further your research using "excel bom php" as I did. There are many other results.

Comment: @One Man Crew: Easiest way to fix this for me was to open the file in notepad++ and under the Encoding tab, make sure to use an encoding that has no BOM at the end.

Comment: @NevinRaj I tried this.. and still not working for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I already tried to search and found this but this not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. The problem was not the script file encode but other include file that wasn't Encode with UTF8 without BOM. 
All the include files have to be with same encode.