# UTF16-LE with BOM not recognizing sep in csv file

Tags: php, csv, byte-order-mark, utf-16le

I need to generate a csv through PHP in UTF16-LE to support Excel (on Windows and Mac OS X). As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16766198/3305116) I used `mb_convert_encoding` and added the BOM at the file start, followed by `sep=;` in order to make it open properly on Excel.

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-16LE');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputs($output, mb_convert_encoding("\xEF\xBB\xBF" . "sep=;\n" . implode($labels, ";") . "\n", 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'));
foreach($data as $data_line) {
    fputs($output, mb_convert_encoding(implode($data_line, ";") . "\n", 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'));
}
```

The character encoding is ok, but when I try to open it in OpenOffice here is what I get:

[image: Open Office UTF16-LE]

The `sep=;\n` isn't recognized - it shouldn't be on the first line. I don't think it's a BOM issue, because when I open it with an hex editor this is what I get:

[image: UTF16-LE BOM]

The BOM seems to be correct, as it's `ÿþ` which is the UTF16-LE BOM. I tried with `\r\n` in place of `\n` after sep, with no luck.

Comment: Is `sep=[value]` an OpenOffice specific directive?  I can't seem to find any references to it.

Comment: I don' think it's a standard as I can't find it in the CSV specification, but it's been used for Excel to force it to use `;` as separator and not tabulations (see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/647948/space-or-tabs-as-separator-in-csv) for example). But Excel doesn't recognize it too, so maybe I use it wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the `sep=;\n` string also be in UTF-16LE?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure if this is the cause of your problems, but an obvious issue I see is that you haven't encoded the `sep=;\n` string as UTF-16LE.

To fix this, change your first `fputs()` line to:

```
$bom = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
$header = $bom . "sep=;\n" . implode($labels, ";") . "\n";
fputs($output, mb_convert_encoding($header, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'));
```

(The string `\xEF\xBB\xBF` is the Unicode Byte Order Mark in the UTF-8 encoding; it will yield the correct BOM when converted to UTF-16.)

Comment: Ah it was a good catch, but sadly I end up with the same result (using the UTF-8 BOM and wrap all with `mb_convert_encoding` - I updated the question code to reflect this).