# PHPExcel export as CSV with ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-csv, phpexcelreader

I have a web page where I have some text boxes and then export button at the end. The function of this is to generate CSV of input data. This works well for an English language input but this creates some problem when I type German language character. I am using PHPExcel library to generate CSV. Here is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['myData'])) {
$obj = $_POST['myData'];
$someArray = json_decode($obj, true);
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$newobjPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$newobjPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
foreach ($someArray as $key => $item) {
        $col = $item['ColID'];
        $colvalue = $item['ColValue'];
        $rowval=$item["ColRow"];
        $newobjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col).$rowval,$colvalue);
    }
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$filename = "Excel_Replace_Output_" . date('Ymd');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.csv"');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($newobjPHPExcel, 'CSV');

$objWriter->save('php://output');}
```

anyone have any idea how to set encoding type for output CSV.

Input : Völklingen

output: VÃ¶lklingen

Thanks

Comment: I changed it to header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
but results still same.

Comment: Add character set of that form also UTF-8

Comment: You mean html character set?

Comment: The charset in the header doesn't make any difference, that applies purely to tell a webbrowser what charset to expect; but applications like MS Excel aren't web browsers

Comment: The file will be generated using UTF-8; so the application that you use to read the file needs to be aware that it is UTF-8.... so what application are you using to open this file?

Comment: And why are you using PHPExcel to generate a csv file when it's a lot more efficient to use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function?

Comment: Yes. You are right. If I export it as Excel5 format then it works fine.

Comment: Ok,let me try this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly)

Comment: Try calling `$objWriter->setExcelCompatibility(true);` immediately before the `save()`