# Export data from mysql with unicode characters

Tags: php, export, georgian

```
<?php
include('db.php');

//header to give the order to the browser
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');

//select table to export the data
$select_table=mysql_query('select * from User');
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);

if ($rows)
{
getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while($rows)
{
getcsv($rows);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
}

// get total number of fields present in the database
function getcsv($no_of_field_names)
{
$separate = '';


// do the action for all field names as field name
foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name)
{
if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name))
{
$field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
}
echo $separate . $field_name;

//sepearte with the comma
$separate = ',';
}

//make new row and line
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Hello, please help me with Unicode problem. This script above works fine it exports everything I need, but all data which is written in Unicode exports like: "??????"

Can anyone help me with modification of this script?

Thank you.

Comment: execute `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");` after connecting and the result with come in utf-8.

Comment: What is the character set set for your db tables ? `utf8` in mysql support limited number of characters,

Comment: After adding mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");  result: "?????" changed to: бѓ—бѓќбѓ бѓњбѓбѓ™бѓ”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change table collation to UTF8
2. In header add this:

   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8")
3. You can try mb_convert_encoding() also.

You can check this link also.[How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bthat-excel-will-read-properly?rq=1)

Comment: I added header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); but same result. :(

Comment: table collation is UTF8

Comment: Did you add 'content-type'?

Comment: I added "mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");" in db.php and header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8"); in export.php

Comment: How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly? worked!!! thank you!