# Laravel : UTF-8 issue while exporting CSV

Tags: php, laravel, csv, utf-8, maatwebsite-excel

While  trying to export data form database I saw some garbage value instead of showing the actual data which is UTF-8 character. I used Excel for opening the csv and I used [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/) package for exporting the csv.

Here is my controller :

```
public function downloadExcel($type)
    {
        $data = Item::get()->toArray();
        return Excel::create('solutionstuff_example', function($excel) use ($data) {

        header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
        header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=solutionstuff_example.csv');
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
```

Here is snap of it:

[image]

If anybody face the problem and know how to fix it.Hope you'll help me to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have some non - UTF-8 charachters that you are trying to display as UTF-8

Comment: I don't understand how could you say those are non -UTF character?

Comment: If it's coming out garbled, it means PHP tried to translate them from their original standard to UTF-8 and failed miserably.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved the problem:

I changed the value: 
`'use_bom'=>false` 
to 
`'use_bom'=>true`

in the `'csv'` part of `excel.php` file in config folder.
I wish you success!

Image details:

[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working in the new version 3.1