# import csv arabic data file

Tags: php, import-from-csv

I have a .CSV file that have an arabic data and i need to import this file into the sql database using PHP.
my code doing it just fine except that the arabic characters inserted into the database as 'ËËËË','ÚÚÚÚ'.

what should i do to insert that data right.

any ideas?

```
 $filename = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']; 
 $file = fopen($filename, "r");
  while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE){
  $emapData[0];
  var_dump($emapData[0]);   //'ËËËË','ÚÚÚÚ'
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Please start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: the problem is in reading the file because the result of the previous `var_dump()` is `ËËËË','ÚÚÚÚ` before i insert it into the database .. i need to read the data in the file in a correct way.

Comment: Sounds like the encoding of the file and the encoding php assumes are off. That is why you have to take care of the encoding configuration of your setup. A direct question: what character encoding _is_ used in that file? And what character encoding _does_ your php setup use internally?

Comment: Consider including an example file and the relevant configuration in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use **PHP office** library...

I think this will help you sort this problem  : [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly/4762708#4762708)