# Codeigniter data to csv character encoding issue with Arabic

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, csv, character-encoding

I'm using codeigniter as a framework with connection characterset

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

Arabic is displayed correctly in the website and database. The issue is with exporting data to a csv file. The file is displayed correctly using code editor on cPanel but when I download the file and open it using excel I get this

[image: issue with arabic]

When I open it with notepad Arabic is displayed correctly but when I upload the file to facebook product catalog it doesn't display Arabic correctly too. here's the code

```
$handler = fopen('./directory/'.$fileName,'a+');

$exporteddata = 'availability,condition,description'.PHP_EOL;
 for ($x=0; $x<count($cat_products); $x++) {
      if(strlen(trim($cat_products[$x]->description)) == '0'){
         $description = ' ';
      }
      else{
         $description = $cat_products[$x]->description;
      }
      $exporteddata .= 'in stock,new,'.$description.PHP_EOL;
 }
fwrite($handler,$exporteddata);
fclose($handler);
```

Then redirect to a function that starts downloading the file using this code

```
public function get_file($file){
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header("Content-Type: application/csv");
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file) . "\"");
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

    $file = 'directory/'.$file;
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found '.$file;
    } elseif (!is_readable($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';
    } else {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 OK');
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

If we ignore the download function and just concentrate on data itself downloaded from file manager from cPanel I still have the issue so it's not just related the download function it's related to the writing function.

So how to fix the encoding issue so that Arabic is displayed correctly in the csv if opened with excel so it can be imported correctly using facebook.

[UPDATE]
When I open the file in notepad and save it with ANSI encoding then open the new file with excel Arabic data is displayed correctly. Can I change the writing encoding to ANSI using php?

Comment: [How to write a utf-8 CSV that Excel will read properly answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly). It's an old question but there's a few answers for recent versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem but still facebook getting wrong encoding I'll contact facebook for that. First

```
mb_convert_encoding($exporteddata, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
fwrite($handler,$exporteddata);
fclose($handler);
```

Second

```
public function get_file($file){
    $file = 'directory/'.$file;
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found '.$file;
    } elseif (!is_readable($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';
    } else {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 OK');
        header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
        header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        header("Content-Type: application/csv");
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

Adding echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; to the download function and mb_convert_encoding to the saving function solved theproblem and Arabic data is displayed correctly in both excel and notepad.