# Export Data Into Excel With Hindi(Unicode) Content in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, unicode, hindi

Actually I have some amount of data stored in mysql database from my website users. Next I want to export this data for user in excel file and i can export data to excel perfectly, But the problem is with unicode content in mysql database, When i am trying to export unicode content into EXCEL it shows like:

```
 à¤•à¥€ à¤‡à¤¤à¤¨à¥‡ à¤²à¤¿à¤Ÿà¤° à¤ªà¤¾à¤¨à¥€ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦ à¤†à¤ª à¤•à¥
```

I am using headers to export, code is below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
```

Please help me out to Export unicode content in excel file.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: That's not a PHP / MySQL problem, its only a problem with excel opening Unicode files.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto  no it's problem with exporting data to excel not with excel.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto i didn't got the solution from that post

Comment: If you create correctly the CSV file in UTF-8 format and you can check the file are OK on a text editor with unicode support, the problem are on Excel side, not PHP side.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto data cannot export in utf 8 format
So how can i export it

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly/4762708#4762708 for how export CSV file in a proper format for Excel Unicode support

Answer (score 0):

That looks like "Mojibake" for the Devanagari `की इतने लिटर पानी के बाद आप क`.

See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of the cause of Mojibake.

It *may* be "double encoding" (also discussed in that link).

The `HEX` for `की` in utf8 is `E0A495 E0A580`; if it is double-encoded, the hex will be `C3A0 C2A4 E280A2 C3A0 C2A5 E282AC`.