# Create CSV problem with loading symbols PHP

Tags: php, csv

I get a problem with symbols if i want to create a CSV.
I get a Â symbol. I think it is a space, but so as you can see i already added charset=UTF-8 to try to fix this problem.

```
 $lines[] = array($product_sku, $product_name, $product_discount, $product_price, $product_quantity, $product_price_total);

header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename";');

echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

$f = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

// First row
fputcsv($f, array('SKU', 'Productnaam', 'Discount', 'Prijs', 'Aantal', 'Totaal prijs'), $delimiter);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
}

// Close the file
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Yes it works, but i did short the code because it is all about the CSV

Comment: Did you read and inwardly digest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through yet?

Comment: no. The problem is the output from my db is the correct output, but when i want to create the CSV file it add weird symbols

Comment: Those `Â` symbols normally mean something in the chain in not UTF-8

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802

Answer (score 1):

The fix was add: `echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM` under the CSV headers