# PHP Generated CSV with UTF8 Characters Not Working as Intended in Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to create -through PHP code- a CSV file that the user will download as a sample, fill it up (probably with Excel), and then re-upload it in order to upload data.

Problem is that the user may decide to use special characters of Russian, Greek languages, etc. (for example Δ,Γ,θ,з,в,и, etc)

What encoding should I use? Because I've noticed that UTF-8 CSV files are not supported when double-clicked to open direct with Excel. (Shows strange characters instead of actual ones)

In all my tries I cant create a sample file that if I will open it directly in Excel it will read those special characters...

I've also tried to use UTF8 with BOM and when i open it with Notepad++ it always shows it is UTF8 format not UTF8-BOM

Comment: `Excel` doesn't support UTF8 well, not a PHP issue. You could use PHPOffice I think... or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly

Comment: I've created (through Notepad++) 3 files in 3 formats ANSI,UTF8, and UTF8BOM, when i edit them and save them Excel saves it to ANSI. So maybe i could just create the csv in ANSI format.