# How can I do a line break in cell of excel using PHP?

Tags: php, excel

Hi I have thw following code:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=archivo.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo "
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Line 1<br>Line 2</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

I have tried:

```
<td>Line 1\r\nLine 2</td>
<td>Line 1".chr(10) . chr(13)."Line 2</td>
```

But nothing seems to work, I need to do a line break in a cell, any suggestions are welcomed. I'm using excel 2010.

I already look at this question: [line break within data for Excel 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765652/line-break-within-data-for-excel-2003) and it didnt work.

It doesnt show error, when I apply `<br>` it creates a new row, when I use `\r\n, \n, or chr(10) . chr(13)`, it creates a space.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try `\n` instead of `\r\n`. Windows uses just `\n` for a new line function.

Comment: try to escape _"_ by _\"_ or use _echo <<<EOF ... EOF;_ ;oP

Comment: This is why I get so frustrated with developers trying to pretend that HTML markup is an Excel file, and then fretting that it doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After searching a lot found this site:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1095-maintaining-line-breaks-in-an-html-excel-file.htm

And this tag solves the issue `<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />`

Thanks for all your comments!!

Comment: I was trying to export a wp list table to .csv. Couldn't for the life in me make the line breaks inside an cell work. I found your answer and tried to export to .xls instead: it's working like a charm! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should add double quotes to include line break

```
'<td>Line 1' . "\r\n" . 'Line 2</td>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a shot with PHP_EOL it should give you the newline character of the operating system you're working on.

Example:

```
$output = 'Line 1' . PHP_EOL .
          'Line 2' . PHP_EOL .
          'Line 3';
```

Comment: Ok, this was fun.. Try using this break tag:
`<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />`

Answer (score 0):

You say *charset="utf-8"* but *chr* returns ASCII!

What about this? ;oP

```
utf8_encode(chr(10).chr(13))
```

Comment: Quid the EOF correction patch on your brackets (i've edited your code)?

Comment: That wouldn't help - UTF-8 encoding of 7-bit character is a no-op, and both CR and LF are 7-bit characters.