# escaping slashes using php

Tags: php, escaping, slash

I am trying to remove the escape sequences present in between my output. I am coding using php and I have output from the function and it contains escape sequences like `\r` and `\n`. How do I escape these stuff from output so that I get a proper output. The issue is that I am trying to add this output to a csv file, so it will take `\n` as next line.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the way I process the data... Im just taking that from the database. I get that in the form "Randall \r\nStephenson"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str_replace function:

```
$your_string =  "here is your string"

$your_string = str_replace("\n", "", $your_string);
$your_string = str_replace("\r", "", $your_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes inhibit escape sequences. `'\r'` is two characters, `\` and `r`; `"\r"` is CR.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stripslashes` and `str_replace` check them out [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value) indicates that keeping the newline in the field should work, so long as:

- newlines inside cells are represented as \n (`str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $cell)`)
- cells are quoted
- rows are terminated with \r\n

If you're not already I'd recommend using [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), as it will take care of the quoting for you.