# concatenate multiline string into one line string php

Tags: php, mysql, string, csv

I am trying to format my mysql data to csv but for some reason when the code gets to physical address the text inside which is multi-lined brakes the output in the csv thus making it non usable.
i've tried trim(), strip_tags() on top of the cleanData() function;

```
function cleanData(&$str)
{
    // escape tab characters
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);

    // escape new lines
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);

    // convert 't' and 'f' to boolean values
    if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
    if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';

    // force certain number/date formats to be imported as strings
    if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
      $str = "'$str";
    }

    // escape fields that include double quotes
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}
```

which is echo'd for download with this code;

```
array_walk($rows,'cleanData');
$trows = implode(",", $rows)."\n";
echo $trows;
```

Is there a way to concatenate/combine a multi-lined string into a single line string without jumping through hoops?

The data is being retrieved from mysql table - which i loop through and add to the array:

```
foreach($row as $data)
{
    if($data != '')
    //echo $data.'<br>';
    $tdata = strip_tags(trim($data));
    array_push($rows, $tdata);
    //echo $tdata.'<br>';
}
```

When it hits the physical address field, i am trying to combine/concatenate the string which is normally entered over a few lines, eg:

```
The Campus 
Cnr Main & Sloane Street
Bryanston, Johannesburg
02021 South Africa
```

I want it as "The Campus Cnr Main & Sloane Street Bryanston Johannesburg 02021 South Africa"
or
    "The Campus \n Cnr Main & Sloane Street\n Bryanston, Johannesburg\n 02021 South Africa"

Comment: Could you give an example when the bug happens? BTW, one possible typo: `$str = "'$str";` should be `$str = "'$str'";`

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value ? And you should probably use something like [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to generate your csv. Generating compliant csv is a solved problem, use someone else's library.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling nope - fputcsv - doesn't solve the problem... and your link shares nothing with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but your question incomplete, the code snippets are in a muddle and your variable names are inconsistent. For instance, you don't `implode(',', $rows)` for CSV. You `implode(',', $cols)` or `implode(',', $row)`, and then `implode("\n", $rows)` (the latter only if you want the data to be in one single string).

I don't know whether your `cleanData()` function only fails to replace the newlines (the `preg_replace` looks ok) or if it's not called at all.

Your code

```
foreach($row as $data)
{
    if($data != '')
    //echo $data.'<br>';
    $tdata = strip_tags(trim($data));
    array_push($rows, $tdata);
    //echo $tdata.'<br>';
}
```

is weird since you commented out a statement after an `if` clause without `{}`. I don't see any `cleanData()` calls here. Try to write an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and I'm quite sure you'll find the problem yourself while doing that.

Oh, to provide another approach for your question. You can do some [replaces in SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) already:

```
select REPLACE(col, "\n", "\\n") from table
```

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for the try but can you try your "solution" and see if it works? It does not work for me, still get the text over a few lines...

Answer (score 0):

I a found solution that fixed my problem from this post;

[How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Fox's answer fixed it =D