# How to support "\n" when exporting csv file with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to export an array data to a csv file, which works fine unless it has break line("\n"). I hope to make it support break line in a single cell, is it possible?

I tried replace \n into "\n" or "'\n'" but it does not work

The function I am using:

```
function arrayToCSVConvertor(arrData, ReportTitle) {
    var CSV='';

    arrData.forEach(function(infoArray, index){
        var dataString = infoArray.join(",");
        //dataString= dataString.split('\n').join('\\n');//Here, need something to suport "\n"
        CSV += dataString+ "\n";
    });

    if (CSV == '') {
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }

    //create a link and click then remove
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.id="lnkDwnldLnk";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    var csv = CSV;
/*    window.open(encodeURI(csv));*/

    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
    //var csvUrl = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var csvUrl = createObjectURL(blob);

    var filename = ReportTitle+'.csv';

    if(navigator.msSaveBlob){//IE 10
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        $("#lnkDwnldLnk")
            .attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href': csvUrl
            });
        $('#lnkDwnldLnk')[0].click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

PS: I have Chinese words inside the array

Comment: Depends on the ["CSV" variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value (also includes target/host - but again, see specific variant rules)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoiding the pain of working with CSV directly and all it's little variants and just use some library like [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) to handle the job for you.

Basically, the new line to be used within a value should be a `\n` and the new line to end a record should be `\r\n` but as @user2864740 commented the results vary based on the encoding of the file and where you are going to open it.

Comment: I need an array , not a JSON, could I have am example for array?

Comment: PapaParse accepts Array of arrays as well as input data, check out the [documentation](http://papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv).