# Handle "Enter" characters from a .csv file

Tags: excel, csv

I have a file that is extracted from a system in a format over which I have no control. It is CSV (UTF-8) and there is a column that contains carriage returns (I'm not sure exactly what they are, but they were originally uploaded from an Excel file with information in the same column but with CTRL+ENTER to change line in the column).

Excel interprets them and changes line, so it creates a new line that does not fit with the headers and is not handled properly when the file is saved as a .csv file again. The text is within text delimiters `"`, so I'm guessing there should be a way to specify the handling of the text inside this delimiter.

I know there's probably no easy way to do that, but is there some VBA code I could use to handle this?

Here is an exemple of what it looks like when it is saved as a csv :

HEADER, GoalLibraryEntry,   GUID,   PARENT_GUID,    LOCALE  name, etc.

ADD,    GoalLibraryEntry,   710103, 710100, en_US,  "Test:,,,,,,,

a) Test1,,,,,,,,,,,
b) Test2,,,,,,,,,,,
c) Blabla,,,,,,,,,,,
d) Blablabla,,,,,,,,,,
e) Test5",,,,,,,,,,,

My problem is very similar to this one : [Generating CSV file for Excel, how to have a newline inside a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value)

However, I've tried saving in ANSI before opening it in Excel without success. I also tried to add UTF-8 BOM at the start, but Excel does not seem to interpret it in any way.

Comment: How is it handling them?  How do you want to handle them?  Keep in mind that I can't see your worksheet or what you mean by, "it creates a new line that does not fit with the headers."

Comment: What do you mean by it creates a new line? do you mean it creates a new row for the data following the carriage return? Could you post an example of what it is doing. and what you need it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I need this to be in only one line so that it can be imported corrrectly back in the system.
What I mean by "does not fit with the headers" is that there are now empty columns created to fit the number of columns in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're most likely seeing is multiline cells made when the user does a alt-enter on the keyboard.

The function you're looking for is clean (eg.) which you could use in VBA.

```
=clean(a1)
```

This removes non-printable characters from a cell.

Comment: I've read about that function, but I don't need to remove the characters, I need them to stay there but not create a new row. The file is then reimported in the system and must contain this information for display purpuses in the system.

Comment: There's probably something you're not telling us.  What does the csv look like?  I've exported one with cell line breaks, and it looks like "foo^Mbar" and it imports fine, and still shows the cell line break.

Comment: It looks a little bit like this : Row 1 - Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4.              
Row 2 - Content1, Content2, Content3 :
Row 3 - Content3 continuity
Row 4 - Again Content3, Content4